# Norm of an operator with $L^2$

Tags: analysis, operator-theory

Let $x(t)$ be continuous on [-1,1] in a space with the $L^2$ norm (i.e. $\lVert x \rVert_2=\sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1} \lvert x(t)\rvert^2dt}$). I have to find the norm of the operator $f(x)$, where $f(x)=\int_{-1}^0x(t)dt -\int_{0}^1x(t)dt$.

I suspect $|f|=\sqrt2$, as
$$|f(x)|=\lvert\int_{-1}^0x(t)dt -\int_{0}^1x(t)dt \rvert$$ $$\le \int_{-1}^0 \lvert x(t) \rvert dt +\int_{0}^1 \lvert x(t) \rvert dt $$ $$= \int_{-1}^1 \lvert x(t) \rvert dt$$ $$\le \sqrt{\left( \int_{-1}^1 \lvert 1 \rvert^2 dt\right)}\sqrt{\left( \int_{-1}^1 \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 dt\right)}$$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals.
$$\implies|f(x)| \le \sqrt2 \lVert x \rVert_2$$

However, I have no idea how to prove that $\sqrt 2$ is the norm by showing it's the infimum. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make all your inequalities into equalities if you take $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,(1_{[-1,0]}-1_{[0,1]})$. As $\|x\|=1$ and $|f(x)|=\sqrt2$, you get that $\|f\|\geq\sqrt2$. And you have already proven the reverse inequality.

As this $x$ is not continuous, we need to approximate. Namely, we need 
$$
x_n(t)=\begin{cases}
1,&\ -1\leq t\leq -1/n\\ \ \\ 
-nt,&\ -1/n\leq t\leq 1/n\\ \ \\
-1,&\ 1/n\leq t\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the x you gave is not continuous as there is a jump at t=0.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that you were working in all of $L^2$. What you need to do is approximate my $x$ with continuous functions.